# Able to see deleted question vote tally from flag-summary page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, flag-history, deleted-posts

I believe that this is probably a bug, although I am not sure. When I go to my flag-summary page, I am able to see links for questions that I have flagged that have since been deleted. If I click the link, I am directed to the 404 page, as I should be; however, I am still able to see the vote tally for the post from my flag-summary page. I believe this to be a bug.

[image: deleted question]

The question shown here has been deleted. I think that I should not be able to see the vote tally.

Comment: Note that it actually have a dark reddish background to indicate that it had been deleted.

Comment: By "vote tally" you mean the score? (-9 in the example)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yep.

Comment: @Ben this is actually feature request ("think that I should not be able to see the vote tally") so is it [meta-tag:status-declined] or will you consider hiding the score?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't read this as a feature request.  He's pointing out behavior that he thinks is incorrect, but is intentional and unlikely to change.  I suppose one could make the case that I should use `status-declined`, but I think `status-bydesign` makes more sense here.

Comment: @BenCollins I don't particularly care one way or the other, so this isn't a feature request. It just seems strange to me that one would be able to see this information. Why is it?

Comment: I agree with @Ben that this is `status-bydesign`. I don't see the problem of knowing the vote count about the post you have previously flagged and seen before. In fact it is kind of useful in knowing how good you are in flagging posts (and how terrible some post can be).